# AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'up' and 'down'

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having an issue where I can't seem to move the character on my screen up and down.

When I run the code and press the down key, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'down'
```

When I run the code and press the up key, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'up'
```

Code:

```
import pygame

class Character():

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):    
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings   
        self.image = pygame.image.load("character.jpg")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.ge_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.centery = self.screen_rect.centery
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)
        self.center1 = float(self.rect.centery)
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False

    def update(self):
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.center += self.ai_settings.char_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.char_speed_factor
        if self.moving_up and self.rect.up < self.screen_rect.up:
            self.center1 += self.ai_settings.char_speed_factor
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.down > 0:
            self.center1 -= self.ai_settings.char_speed_factor
        self.rect.centerx = self.center
        self.rect.centery = self.center1

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

This is just the character class python file and not the main file. There is a game functions file which checks for keyboard input and then sets the self.moving variables to True. The definitions in the gamefunctions file are then called in the main file. I am very confused as to why this is happening because I have no trouble with getting the character to move left and right.

Comment: Can we see the full stack trace? Cant do much with one line from a error and it looks like it may be somewhere in the event handler.

Comment: @Pygasm The error is very clearly stated in the error message. OP must have tried to refer to the attribute `down` and `up` of a `Rect` object (when there is none).

Comment: Oh, I wasnt looking in the right places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies within those four lines of the code, where you check for movement and the respective border collision:

```
class Character():
    # Other methods...

    def update(self):
        # Other if clauses...
        if self.moving_up and self.rect.up < self.screen_rect.up:
            self.center1 += self.ai_settings.char_speed_factor
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.down > 0:
            self.center1 -= self.ai_settings.char_speed_factor
        # ...
```

Notice that you are comparing the `up` and `down` attributes of `Rect` objects, which does not in fact exist. Perhaps you meant `top` and `bottom`?

In addition, the logic of your code is incorrect. You are checking whether `self.rect.bottom` is greater than zero when it is moving down — however, to properly implement border collision mechanics, you should check for whether it is less than the screen's height (which I presumed to be `self.screen_rect.bottom`) when it is moving down. The opposite goes with `self.rect.top` — you should check for whether it is greater than zero.

Corrected `if` statements:

```
# Replaced .up with .top and .down with .bottom
# Corrected .top and .bottom comparison
if self.moving_up and self.rect.top > 0:
    self.center1 -= self.ai_settings.char_speed_factor
if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
    self.center1 += self.ai_settings.char_speed_factor
```